# Ratio test for $Σ ne^{-n^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I show that the infinite series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ne^{-n^2}}$

is converging using the ratio test?

I know that the result $p$ has to be less than 1, so I have already used the theorem and gotten:

$p = \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}$

which gives $\frac{(n+1)e^{-(n+1)^2}}{ne^{-n^2}}$

so what I struggle with is the next step, to simplify it. Is there a rule or way you guys could show me or advise me so I can solve this and similar problems with?
the textbook over complicates everything

thankyou so much in advance:)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Yes, i apologize, I have added more context to it now.

Comment: It is not clear which series (not equation) you are talking about.

Comment: It is an infinite series

Comment: do you mean $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot e^{(-n)^2}$

Comment: yes except the n = 1

Comment: Please look at the way I have reformatted your question.  You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to forma questions on this site.

Comment: @Cornman very likely not.  It should instead be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot e^{-(n^2)}$ instead.  Otherwise there would be no point in including the negative sign or the iterated powers.

Comment: No, the way the professor formulated the question is n = 1, and yes I am new here. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{(n+1)e^{-(n+1)^2}}{ne^{-n^2}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot e^{-(n+1)^2+n^2}=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot e^{-2n-1}.
$$
The first term converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$; what does the second term do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\frac{n+1}{n}\to1,$ so you only have to deal with $\frac{e^{-(n+1)^2}}{e^{-n^2}},$ and the laws of exponents take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown
the ratio test.
The root test also works.

$(ne^{-n^2})^{1/n}
=n^{1/n}e^{-n}
$
and this goes to zero
quite strongly
(all that is needed
is that is is less than 1).